# How to retrieve only nouns from a file and pass them as an array to LSA?

Tags: python, arrays, pos-tagger, lsa

I need to extract only those words whose tags match with pos-tags variable of program and pass those words to LSI model but when i print nouns i get an empty list.

Here is my sample input of noun file:

```
['All,DT', 'praise,NN', 'is,VBZ', 'due,JJ', 'to,TO', 'God,NNP', 'alone,RB', ',,,', 'the,DT', 'Sustainer,NNP', 'of,IN', 'all,PDT', 'the,DT', 'worlds,NNS', ',,,', '\n']
['The,DT', 'Most,JJS', 'Gracious,JJ', ',,,', 'the,DT', 'Dispenser,NNP', 'of,IN', 'Grace,NNP', ',,,', '\n']
['Lord,NNP', 'of,IN', 'the,DT', 'Day,NNP', 'of,IN', 'Judgment,NN', '!,.', '\n']
['Thee,NNP', 'alone,RB', 'do,VBP', 'we,PRP', 'worship,NN', ';,:', 'and,CC', 'unto,JJ', 'Thee,NNP', 'alone,RB', 'do,VBP', 'we,PRP', 'turn,VB', 'for,IN', 'aid,NN', '.,.', '\n']
['Guide,NNP', 'us,PRP', 'the,DT', 'straight,JJ', 'way,NN', '.,.', '\n']
```

Here is my sample code:

```
import nltk
import os.path
import re
import gensim
from gensim import corpora, models
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities

thefile='E://noun.txt'
file3 = open(thefile,'r',encoding='utf8')
nouns=[]
arr=[]
arr1=[]
pos_tags = ('NN','NNS', 'NNPS')
for line in file3.readlines():
    nouns.append([j.split(',')[0] for i in line for j in i if any(j.endswith(p) for p in pos_tags)])
print(nouns)
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(nouns)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(inp) for inp in nouns]
# extract 400 LSI topics; use the default one-pass algorithm
lsi = models.lsimodel.LsiModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=10)
# print the most contributing words (both positively and negatively) for each of the first ten topics
arr1.append(lsi.print_topics(10))
print(arr1)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to do with your list comprehension (after `nouns.append(...` ).  Right now it looks like you are iterating over every character in `line` (`for i in line`) and then iterating over each character individually (`for j in i`), then checking if each character ends with one of your POS tags (which none of them do since all your POS tags are multi character strings).  Remember that you read strings with `readlines()`, not lists. You are missing a processing step to convert each line to a list and then you probably need to rethink your list comprehension.

Comment: In my input file as every word is in two parts i.e. first part is word and the second is its pos tag separated with comma. I am iterating over every word and checking its tag and if that tag exists in pos_tags variable then that word is appended in nouns list.

Comment: `[word.split(',')[0] for word in line.split() if word.split(',')[1] in pos_tags]`

Comment: @bunji It is giving list index out of range error.

Comment: then you have some words that don't have part of speech tags